# How do you install interbase.so and pdo_firebird.so php extensions on macos these days?

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, php-extension, pecl

I’ve been up and down google for an entire day but couldn’t find anything that works. Any suggestions? i’m using php73 installed with brew on catalina.

Answer (score 1):

**Instructions:**

1. Find your extension php directory:

   `php-config --extension-dir`
2. Move your extensions to the above directory.
3. Find your php.ini file.

   `php -ini | grep 'Loaded Configuration File'`
4. Add the following lines to your php.ini:

   `extension=interbase.so`

   `extension=pdo_firebird.so`
5. Verify extension:

   `php -m`

Answer (score 0):

You can find interbase.so on the [firebird website](https://firebirdsql.org/en/php-driver/) supports php7.4 with 8.0 support in beta (already in the github repo)

Copy it using steps @Jairus provided.

Install Firebird Server. Suspect you'll be able to do the same with Brew.

*Ubuntu example*

```
sudo apt install firebird-server
sudo apt-get install -y php7.4-pdo-firebird
```

Also found an example of compiling for Mac M1
[Installing Firebird on Mac M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69955752/how-do-i-build-the-firebird-database-extension-ext-interbase-for-php-on-a-maco/69955753#69955753)