# How do I build the Firebird database extension (ext-interbase) for PHP on a MacOS M1 Monterey?

Tags: macos, firebird, apple-m1

## Firebird Extension for PHP on MacOS M1

I have PHP7.4 installed with homebrew and the Xcode command line tools.

I followed the instructions as per the source repository here https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/php-firebird using the following methodology, I have changed the Linux formula to suite the MacOS library locations as per this answer here
[Issues compiling firebird driver for PHP-7.4 on macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67614393/issues-compiling-firebird-driver-for-php-7-4-on-macos):

```
git clone https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/php-firebird.git
cd php-firebird
phpize
CPPFLAGS=-I/Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Headers LDFLAGS=-L/Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Resources/lib ./configure
make
```

The error I get is

```
configure: error: libfbclient, libgds or libib_util not found! Check config.log for more information.
```

In the log file it refers to the following which is the crux of the issue

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/firebird/lib/libib_util.dylib, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
```

The problem is that the Firebird package for Mac is only built for the 64bit architecture and not the ARM architecture.

Comment: I recommend you create an issue on https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/issues about the lack of a M1 build of Firebird, and an issue on https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/php-firebird/issues for php-firebird.

Answer (score 3):

## Solution

I always seem to struggle building the extension for Firebird on MacOS (Intel or M1) and after a month of leaving the problem I discovered the solution which I leave here for myself all of you who have hit this wall, until ARM is supported on MacOS for Firebird we probably have to run the 64 bit version with 64 bit PHP.  The steps below should get you up and running.  I came up with 2 solutions, the first most obvious one was to make a docker build.

### Docker Solution

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/app tina4stack/php -ini | grep interbase
```

### Home brew solution

The second solution (more complicated) was to follow these steps, I don't always like to run a docker engine for simple things.

#### Install latest Firebird for MacOS

First, make sure you have installed the latest Firebird MacOS package, Firebird 3.0 at the time of writing has only one you can install.

The next problem I ran into was home-brew had installed an ARM version of PHP which made the linking to the x86_64 architecture impossible.  Kudos to the documentation here https://austencam.com/posts/setting-up-an-m1-mac-for-laravel-development-with-homebrew-php-mysql-valet-and-redis

#### Install Rosetta

First I installed Rosetta (helps run 64 bit apps on MacOS ARM)

```
/usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
```

#### Install Home-brew for 64bit architecture

Next I removed homebrew and reinstalled it with the arch -x86_64 bit flag

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
```

```
arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

#### Install PHP7.4

Then installed a fresh php@7.4

```
 arch -x86_64 brew install php@7.4
```

#### Compile the extension

```
git clone https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/php-firebird.git
cd php-firebird
phpize
CFLAGS='-arch x86_64' CPPFLAGS=-I/Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Headers LDFLAGS=-L/Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Resources/lib ./configure
make
sudo make install
```

#### Tying it all together

I added the following to my php.ini file

```
extension=interbase
```

If you don't know where to edit your ini file, run the following command:

```
php -ini | grep php.ini
```

When I ran php -ini | grep interbase I got errors about not finding the firebird libraries.  In the end I copied the libraries to the PHP bin and lib folders

```
cp /Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Resources/lib/* /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.25/lib
```

```
cp /Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Resources/lib/* /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.25/bin
```

I'm sure someone could comment on making the above a bit neater but I was happy to find that the ini command returns now as expected.

```
php -ini | grep interbase
interbase
```

Let me know if you hit issues I didn't find, there were some other things I tried for the Firebird library resolution but I'm not sure they worked.

**Installing modules with PECL**

As an addition the the above solution, easily install other PHP modules using the following command

```
arch -x86_64 pecl install <module>
```

*Example*

```
arch -x86_64 pecl install openswoole
```